# SimpleDateFormat java and Convert.ToDateTime() C#

Tags: c#, android, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I am working on an Android app that communicates with a web server (written in C#) using XML. At some point, from the app I send and EndDate parameter like so:

```
public Request SendRequest(Date endDate)
{
setPostData("EndDate", StringUtils.gmtDateFormat.format(endDate));
}
```

I think `format` will convert the date to string.

Where `StringUtils.cs` is defined as:

```
public class StringUtils {

    public static final SimpleDateFormat gmtDateFormat;

    static {           
        // When sending dates to the server
        gmtDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", Locale.US);
        gmtDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        gmtDateFormat.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"), Locale.US));
          }
}
```

The web server converts the string sent form the app into a `DateTime` by

```
Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["EndDate"]);
```

and this is where I get the following error:

```
Message: ...EndDate=2015-0005-13T06%3a00%3a00.00%2b0000...
Exception: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
at System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)
```

There are two problems here

1. 2015-0005-13 should be 2015-05-13
2. Where did 06%3a00%3a00.00%2b0000 come from?

Comment: Why would you sent the date as a string? Send it as a long, it's the safest way to avoid any kind of parsing errors.

Comment: how would I convert it to long?

Comment: in java just use date.getTime(), and in C# you can use date.Ticks (assuming you are using DateTime), after that you can construct a new Date or DateTime from the long (the long represents the miliseconds of the date)

Comment: Quick note: I made a mistake there, one tick is actually 1/10000 of a milisecond, so you'd have to divide it to get the miliseconds to use in for the java Date object.

Comment: It seems you're mixing up the Date object with the DateTime object. SimpleDateFormat is the Date object.  DateTime is much better to use.

Comment: For DateTime I would have to use library http://www.joda.org/joda-time/quickstart.html

Comment: How is DateTime going to solve my problem?

Comment: @AdnanElezovic - Sending a date as an ISO-8601 formatted string is very common and quite safe if done correctly.

Comment: Also, C# `DateTime` ticks are based on an epoch of 0001-01-01, and varies by `Kind`.  Java uses the Unix epoch  of 1970-01-01 that is fixed to UTC.  Sure, you can convert, but that requires this outside knowledge.  The ISO8601 standard is ubiquitous.

Comment: @AlanFord - Is it possible that your `setPostData` method is the one applying the URL encoding?  Have you checked what's coming over the wire itself via Fiddler or similar?